# How can I wait for jQuery.ajaxComplete within promise.done before returning a result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I'm trying to do set a value within jQuery's ajaxComplete, and ask for that value when a promise completes.  The issue I'm running into is that jQuery's ajaxComplete runs after the promise.done.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, jqXhr) {
    // Set a value here
});

var promise = $.post(url,{});
promise.done(function(){
    // Ask for the value here, but wait on ajaxComplete before returning it
});
```

Is there some way I can defer the return of the value until after jQuery's ajaxComplete finishes?  I've looked at jQuery's deferred methods but I am unsure how to use it in conjunction with ajaxComplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajaxComplete` provides no hooks for this case. The event will always fire *after* the deferred is resolved. We can see it in the source code:

```
// Complete
completeDeferred.fireWith(callbackContext, [jqXHR, statusText]);

if (fireGlobals) {
    globalEventContext.trigger("ajaxComplete", [jqXHR, s]);
    // Handle the global AJAX counter
    if (! (--jQuery.active)) {
        jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStop");
    }
}
```

You'd have to implement it yourself, for example by deferring the execution of the `then` handlers by an additional timeout:

```
 function defer(val){
     var d = $.Deferred();
     setTimeout(function(){ d.resolve(val); }, 0);
     return d.promise();
 }
```

Which would mean:

```
var promise = $.post(url, {}).then(defer);
promise.done(function(){
   // all here
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful.  In my case the value is always set, so I need to also guarantee that the data is not stale when the deferred resolves.  Maybe I need to version it somehow within the ajaxComplete?

Comment: That is correct but to be fair I wouldn't. Instead I'd wrap `$.post` myself and add my own `ajaxComplete` logic through _that_ function instead which would let you have a lot more fine graining in what executes first and you wouldn't have to resort to stuff like timeouts.

Comment: I'm using the global ajaxComplete to look for specific headers.  When it finds them, it will display a message to the user and increment a counter.  I felt like that was the correct place for it as it is done globally for all ajax requests.  The promise.done has a stale version of the incremented counter information.I was hoping I didn't have to do anything special with the $.post as then I have to do it for every $.post in which I need the correct value of the incremented counter.